# Does the non-generic version of IEnumerable support deferred execution?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, deferred-execution

If so, on what .NET Framework versions is it supported?

I have tested this on .NET Framework 4.0 and it works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TestClass
{
    public IEnumerable Defer()
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterators (yield keyword) first became available in C# version 2, shipped with VS2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is supported ever since the `yield` keyword was. The only difference is that it's more or less `IEnumerable<object>`, which might lead to inefficiencies if it has to do boxing. Other than that, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Deferred execution has nothing to do with `yield`. `yield` is just syntax sugar. There is no reason why you cannot have deferred execution in .NET 1.0 using `IEnumerable`.

Comment: True. But, the OP's example specifically uses yield which would indicate he's not targeting 1.0. (Is anyone these days?)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that yield is just syntactic sugar. As for using 1.0, I agree

Answer (score 1):

As the `yield` keywords are reduced to compiler trickery, presumably this should work.  It certainly works for the 2.0 runtime; I'd hesitate to make any statements about 1.1, however.

Answer (score 1):

The non-generic IEnumerable does not implement IDisposable.  It may be that VB.Net and C# will duck-type either IDisposable or the .Dispose() method when using an enumerator that does not support IEnumerable(Of T), but one can certainly not rely upon all consumers of the non-generic IEnumerable to do so.  If the consumer of an enumerable does not properly .Dispose() it, execution of the enumerator, *including explicit or implicit finally clauses*, will be abandoned.

Comment: I'm looking for more information on this; I just can't wrap my head around this apparent glaring design flaw with IEnumerable. I was reading this article, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About, which states under "Backwards Compatibility" that client code expecting non-generic IEnumerator's does not properly dispose of the iterator. What sort of error could this cause?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: Consider the case of a collection which is used in multiple threads.  If all code that enumerates the collection calls `GetEnumerator`, quickly enumerates the collection, and then calls `Dispose` on that enumerator, then having `GetEnumerator` acquire a lock and having `Dispose` release it might work well.  If `Dispose` never gets called, however, code needing to use the collection might get blocked indefinitely.  One could perhaps work around this by having the collection hold a reference which will identify the active enumerator (if one exists), and have code that would...

Comment: ...check whether the lock is being held by an enumerator and--if so--start by waiting a little while for the lock.  If that fails, the code could then engage a secondary lock [which the enumerator would have to acquire and release each time it actually gets an element], enumerate the remainder of the collection to a list, tell the enumerator to fetch remaining data from that list, and then steal the primary lock.  That would add a lot of complexity, however, which wouldn't be needed if users of the enumerator adhere to proper discipline.

Comment: Understood. So does this mean that having IEnumerator<T> inherit from IEnumerator breaks the Liskov substitution principle? You can't just pass someone an IEnumerator<T> when they specify in the interface that they accept all IEnumerator's, because then such interfaces won't dispose of the IEnumerator<T>, which could cause a locking problem as you've described.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: The problem fundamentally is `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` may return any of three things: "object that can be safely abandoned but doesn't implement `IDisposable`", "object that can be abandoned only calling `Dispose`", or "object that can be safely abandoned with or without calling `Dispose`, and there's no nice way for client code to handle all three.  `IEnumerable<T>` guarantees it won't return objects of the first type.  The original designers of `IEnumerable` may have expected that it would never return objects of the second type, but that was never realistic.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: IMHO, the real problem is that both `IEnumerable` and `IEnuerable<T>`, along with `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<T>` omit features and properties which all implementations should be able to support, e.g. "will calling `GetEnumerator` yield an object that may be safely abandoned", "do you know how many items you contain", or "will you always report the same contents".  This should be handled by using a property, rather than having different interfaces, so as to allow enumerators to be wrapped by other enumerators without an explosion of wrapper types.